# Getting error "Failed to decrypt settings..." when trying to start Azure bot function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have a bot endpoint implemented as an Azure function and it's running fine within Azure.

We've followed this process to enable us to run/debug the Azure Function locally:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local

In particular, the following PowerShell command:

```
func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings <FunctionAppName>
```

It appears to run fine and put the necessary settings into local.settings.json, which is output to bin when the project is built. However, when we start the function (Right click project - Debug - Start new instance) it gives this error:

```
Failed to decrypt settings. Encrypted settings only be edited through 'func settings add'.
```

On two machines we are getting the above decryption error, on two machines it is running fine.

Any suggestions?

P.S. We are not trying to share the same local.settings.json file between machines, which I understand would also yield this sort of error.

UPDATE

Here is the content of the local.settings.json file from a problem machine, with encrypted values removed:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": true,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "[encrypted content]",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "[encrypted content]",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "[encrypted content]",
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING": "[encrypted content]",
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE": "[encrypted content]",
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "[encrypted content]",
    "BotEnv": "[encrypted content]",
    "BotId": "[encrypted content]",
    "MicrosoftAppId": "[encrypted content]",
    "MicrosoftAppPassword": "[encrypted content]",
    "BotStateEndpoint": "[encrypted content]",
    "BotOpenIdMetadata": "[encrypted content]",
    "UseTableStorageForConversationState": "[encrypted content]",
    "BotDevAppInsightsKey": "[encrypted content]",
    "BotDevAppInsightsName": "[encrypted content]",
    "BotDevAppInsightsAppId": "[encrypted content]",
    "AzureWebJobsBotFrameworkDirectLineSecret": "[encrypted content]",
    "AzureWebJobsBotFrameworkDirectLineEndpoint": "[encrypted content]",
    "WEBSITE_USE_PLACEHOLDER": "[encrypted content]",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[encrypted content]",
    "MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES": "[encrypted content]"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {}
}
```

Comment: Could you show this `local.settings.json` file (secrets obfuscated)?

Comment: I have added the `local.settings.json` file content to the question but omitted the encrypted values, is that what you meant?

Comment: What type of authentication the function app is using.. like anonymous or function key etc?

Comment: We are using an AppId and Password stored in the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword settings. I understand that these are only required when we try to connect to Azure Storage. We've tested the AppId and password are correct, and these settings work when hosted in Azure. There seems to be some sort of local issue where the `func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings` PowerShell script creates encrypted settings that the local func.exe cannot decrypt.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is as everything you're doing seems fine. Is the user who ran fetch, the same as the one who is trying to read the secrets? can you try setting `CLI_DEBUG = 1` environment variable and run `func settings list` from that window? That exception is only used if decrypt function throws, so I'm a bit baffled how it can write a file it can't read again.

Answer (score 50):

Change the falue of **IsEncrypted** as follows :

```
"IsEncrypted": false,
```

in 
     `local.settings.json`

Comment: This will not fix the issue, but just disable the encryption while the values are still encrypted.

Comment: it should be added in the local.settings.json , at the higher level of the json, in other words outside of the values object

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same problems:

After doing :

> func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings

I got only encrypted function settings in `local.settings.file`. Debugging with `func stettings list` and looking at `func settings list --help` revealed that i can do:

> func settings decrypt

and worked!

**EDIT:**
Just coming back some months later. Using the explicit `"IsEncrypted": false` in function.json works for me now as well, however it may be better to use `func settings decrypt`

Comment: This should mark as answer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when running different runtime version v1 and v2. Check if you are running same Function Runtime Version.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to encrypt by running 'func encrypt'
But before doing this, you need to make sure IsEncripted is set to false. (I set this to true manually)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible situations:

1. If your project have a `local.settings.json` file, then the `func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings <FunctionAppName>` command will follow the `IsEncrypted` property defined in the `local.settings.json` file. If the `IsEncrypted` property set as `true`, then the downloaded application settings will be `Encrypted`. Otherwise, the downloaded settings will be `Decrypted`.

   For example, assume the following `local.settings.json` already exists in your project. After download the application settings from Azure, the result will be Unencrypted values.

   ```json
   {
     "IsEncrypted": false,
     "Values": {
       "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
       "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
     },
     "ConnectionStrings": {}
   }
   ```
2. If your project don't have a `local.settings.json` file before you run `func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings <FunctionAppName>` command, then you will download an **Encrypted** version of the `local.settings.json` file. You need run `func settings decrypt` command to decrypt the file.